# Docker container does/doesnt work inside kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am a bit confused here. It does work as normal docker container but when it goes inside a pod it doesnt. So here is how i do it.

> Dockerfile in my local to create the image and publish to docker registry

```
FROM alpine:3.7
COPY . /var/www/html
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

Now if i just pull the image(after deleting the local) and run as a container. It works and i can see my files inside /var/www/html.

Now i want to use that inside my kubernetes cluster.

> Def : Minikube --vm-driver=none

I am running kube inside minikube with driver none option. So for single node cluster.

### EDIT

***I can see my data inside /var/www/html if i remove volume mounts and claim from deployment file.***

> Deployment file

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: app
  name: app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: app
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        runAsGroup: 1000
      containers:
      - image: kingshukdeb/mycode
        name: pd-mycode
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/www/html
          name: claim-app-storage
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: claim-app-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: claim-app-nginx
status: {}
```

> PVC file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: app-nginx1
  name: claim-app-nginx
spec:
  storageClassName: testmanual
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
status: {}
```

> PV file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: app-nginx1
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: testmanual
  capacity:
    storage: 100Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/data/volumes/app"
```

Now when i run these files it creates the pod, pv, pvc and pvc is bound to pv. But if i go inside my container i dont see my files. `hostpath` is **/data/volumes/app** . Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: go to `var/www/html` data will be there

Comment: Its not. Thats why the question.

Comment: check in host path data available there.

Comment: Usually in Kubernetes you'd just run the code out of the built image, rather than trying to replicate it by hand to every single node, with a consistent version, at a consistent path.  Does your application work if you delete all of the machinery to override the image contents?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes you are right. I can see my files inside /var/www/html if i remove pv and pvc.

Comment: @DavidMaze is there anyway i can use pv and pvc because i need to share those files with other pods too which resides inside same node.

Answer (score 0):

When PVC is bound to a pod, volume is mounted in location described in pod/deployment yaml file. In you case: `mountPath: /var/www/html`. That's why files "baked into" container image are not accessible (simple explanation why [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3253))

You can confirm this by exec to the container by running `kubectl exec YOUR_POD -i -t -- /bin/sh`, and running `mount | grep "/var/www/html"`.

### Solution

You may solve this in many ways. It's best practice to keep your static data separate (i.e. in PV), and keep the container image as small and fast as possible.

If you transfer files you want to mount in PV to your hosts path `/data/volumes/app` they will be accessible in your pod, then you can create new image omitting the `COPY` operation. This way even if pod crashes changes to files made by your app will be saved.

If PV will be claimed by more than one pod, you need to change `accessModes` as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes):

> The access modes are:
>
> - ReadWriteOnce – the volume can be mounted as read-write by a single node
> - ReadOnlyMany – the volume can be mounted read-only by many nodes
> - ReadWriteMany – the volume can be mounted as read-write by many nodes

In-depth explanation of Volumes in Kubernetes docs:  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/

Comment: As far as i understand...i am mounting my container's /var/www/html directory to hosts /data/volumes/app directory. So whatever data or files i have in container's var/www/html directory will be available inside hosts /data/volumes/app directory. As per your comment seems its other way around. Like data from /data/volumes/app will be available inside container's /var/www/html. I am not sure if thats right. Though thats certainly right for docker.

Comment: Yes, you understood that correctly.  Would that suit your use-case?

Comment: Not really. I want to use my images to provide the data. Now when you mount folderA to folderB, its true that folderA's data will be at folderB. But its also the other way around. If you add data/files in folderB, those should also be visible at folderA. Thats how mount works right?